# Film Location of Don Ciccio's Villa

Tags: film-location, the-godfather-2

Can anyone tell me the location of Don Ciccio's villa?

It was used twice in GF II.  Once for the death of Vito's mother, and Vito's subsequent escape.  Then again, when the adult Vito returns to Sicily to kill Don Ciccio.

And, no, it isn't Castello degli Schiavi, which was used in all three films.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Godfather Wikia](http://godfather.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:17061), it is located in a villa near Taormina, Sicily.  This placename is confirmed on other sites, such as [this one](http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/g/Godfather-2.php).

The coordinates which can be viewed in Google Earth are given in the first link as 37°39'42.45"N, 15°10'32.83"E.  Descriptions of this villa are described in this first link.